# Select a Column without using .Select

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA macro in excel. It works; however, every forum I read states I should avoid using Select. As I am a newbie, I do not know how to implement it nor how it would work.

The code does the following:

1. Copy contents in Column B to Column E, then delete Column B

   - Column E then becomes Column D
2. Format all cells in Column D to wrap text
3. Use Data text to Column feature on Column D

   - Delimiter based on line breaks. (Other: CTRL J)

```
Sub TestRun()
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("D:D").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 25.13

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="" & Chr(10) & "", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
        , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Columns("D:D").Select` - `Dim myRange As Range`, and then use `Set MyRange = Columns("D:D")` - then use that object variable instead of `Selection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just replace .Select with the Method (action) or Property (attribute) that you will be using. Then delete all unecessary actions that Select would normally do. For example:

```
Sub TestRun()
    Columns("B:B").Copy Destination:=Columns("E:E")
    Columns("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    With Columns("D:D")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .ColumnWidth = 25.13
        .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="" & Chr(10) & "", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
        , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using the `With` statement with out using variables to move col2 to col4.

```
'Identify your workbook and sheet, change the sheet name as needed
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'First - Cut col2 
    .Columns(2).EntireColumn.Cut

    'Second - Insert col2 at col5 shifting the current col5 to the right. 
    .Columns(5).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight

    'col3 etc. will then shift left because col2 was cut and moved to col5
End With
```

You can use `With Columns(4)` inside the above `With` statement to format the column, try to write the code and if you have any more questions then please ask.

Comment: It works thank you very much!